# Is there a way to get sharepoint 2013 to automatically copy emails from outlook into a blog or other master list?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, automation

In my org, there's a team who controls some of our policy and procedure. It's currently announced and tracked through a series of emails to the team, but that's less than ideal.

I'm going to set up a sharepoint page on our site where we can house these change emails and revisit them in a centralized location. Is there a way to automate the process of taking the content of the email and creating an entry on a sharepoint page of it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:
1. At Sharepoint, create "email enabled" document library. This will allow you send emails to library email address, email letter will be stored in this doc library.
2. For this doc library,  create event receiver and handle onaitemadded(read email body and create or update corresponsing Sharepoint page)